# In Rest Assured while trying to get token facing issue "Failed to parse the JSON document"

Tags: api, selenium, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

```
public void appTocken() {
RestAssured.baseURI ="https://localhost";
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

String payload= "{   \"client_id\": \"ahsan@gmail.com\",\r\n"
        + "    \"client_secret\": \"1212\",\r\n"
        + "    \"isInternalUser\": true,\r\n"
        + "    \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\"\r\n"
        + "}";
request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
Response responseFromApp =  request.body(payload).post("/auth/oauth/oidc/login-token");
responseFromApp.prettyPrint();
```

String jsonString = responseFromApp.getBody().toString();
String tockenGenerated = JsonPath.from(jsonString).get("access_token");

}

Comment: what s there in jsonstring

Comment: @PDHide to extract Token I am converting it to string. Also note that while I am trying to print on line above responseFromApp.prettyPrint(); I am not getting any thing.

Comment: means you got an empty response back

Comment: try printing jsonstring and see if it has any value

Comment: On printing jsonString it shows " io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@5707c1cb "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String jsonString = responseFromApp.getBody().toString();
```

converts the object into string string object it doesn't give the json string , use :

```
String jsonString = responseFromApp.getBody().asString();
```

if pretty print is empty then asString() also will be empty

A working example:

```
Response maxJson = RestAssured
            .given().header("Content-type", "application/json").body("{\r\n"
                    + "         \"name\": \"morpheus\",\r\n" + "            \"job\": \"leader\"\r\n" + "        }")
            .post("https://reqres.in/api/users");
    maxJson.prettyPrint();

    String jsonString = maxJson.getBody().asString();
    System.out.println(jsonString);
```